# Can I get $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis

> For a sequence $\{f_n\}$ and every $f_n$ is continuous. Can I get $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous?

The definition of equicontinuous is that for each $x\in X$, for every $\epsilon >0$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ s.t. $\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid<\epsilon$ for all $y\in U$ and all $n$.

So if I show that every $f_n$ is continuous, then $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous?

Comment: What is $g_n$? Something's missing here.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, just $f_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, equicontinuity implies continuity but not the other way. Consider the sequence of functions $\{nx\}$ which are all clearly continuous and let $\epsilon = 1$ and consider around the point $x = 0$. Well for any $y\in (-\delta, \delta)$ we have that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $|nx - ny| = n|x-y|<n\delta$. So we can always make $n$ large enough so that $n\delta > 1$. Hence $\{nx\}$ is a sequence of functions which are continuous but not equicontinuous.

Comment: Even a bounded sequence can fail to be equicontinuous. E.g. $X=[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)=x^n$............+1

Comment: But if I can show that for $\epsilon>0$ and there exists a $\delta$ such that $\mid x-y\mid<\delta$, $\mid f_n(x)-f_n(y)\mid < \epsilon$ for all $x, y$ and $n$. And $\delta$ is independent from the $n$. Can I get it is equicontinuous?

Comment: Yes, equicontinuity strengthens uniform continuity to also be independent of the n